# How to print text between 2 patterns with wildcards?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, wildcards

I need to capture the text between two patterns, but those patterns may contain numbers that change. Also I only care about lines with this structure that begin with that letter sequence, any other sequence or structure should be ignored. They can be double digit numbers on the left hand side of what I'm trying to capture, but on the right hand side the number of digits will remain the same

Ex:

```
ab-cd-1.1.1.11-CAPTURE-11111111.xyz
```

Or

```
ab-cd-22.1.11.1-CAPTURE-11111112.xyz
```

Using the below command I can get what I need if I assume the numbers don't change, but am not sure how to account for random numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
echo "ab-cd-1.1.1.11-CAPTURE-11111111.xyz" | sed "s/.*ab-cd-1.1.1.11-//;s/-.*//"
```

Comment: Is that structure to the left always the same, like `cc-cc-n.n.n.nn`?

Comment: Do you want to get "CAPTURE"? Beside change of letters and numbers are there any other changes?

Comment: @RudiC the letters are always the same, but the numbers can change so it can be cc-cc-n.nn.n.nn

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes just CAPTURE. Right hand side length is always the same, just random numbers. Left hand side letters always the same, but numbers can change

Comment: @devanon, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `awk` using `-` to separate the tokens:

```
awk -F\- '{print $4}' input_file
```

If you want to apply other filters this is one possible way:

```
<exec some filter based on other fields> input_file|awk -F\- '{print $4}'
```

According to your edited answer and if you expect the string to start with `ab-cd` the script will be

```
awk -F\- '$1=="ab" && $2=="cd" {print $4}' input_file
```

Base on the last requirements this is the script:

```
awk -F\- '$1=="ab" && $2=="cd" {split($5,a,"."); if (int(a[1])==a[1] && length(a[1])==8) print $4}' input_file
```

My test with file:

```
cat qq
ab-cd-1.1.1.11-CAPTURE-11111111.xyz
ab-cd-1.1.1.11-CAPTURa-1111111a.xyz
ab-cd-1.1.1.11-CAPTURb-1111111.xyz
ab-cd-1.1.1.11-aAPTURE-a1111112.xyz


awk -F\- '$1=="ab" && $2=="cd" {split($5,a,"."); if (int(a[1])==a[1] && length(a[1])==8) print $4}' qq
CAPTURE
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply. That does work, but I think I wasn't clear in my question. I will always look for those same letters on the left, but they're can be other patterns of letters that should cause me to ignore the entire line

Comment: @devanon, check my edited answer. And if you share the other filters probably we will be able to incorporate them in `awk` :)

Comment: I updated the original post so I think it makes more sense. I only need to filter for this structure and beginning letter sequence, any other pattern/sequence must be ignored @Romeo Ninov

Comment: @devanon, I edit my answer, please check and clarify if its not what you search for.

Comment: I think this works. I was caught up on the numbers, but since this checks for the beginning sequence I think it should be ok to ignore checking for how many numbers on right hand side etc...thanks! @Romeo Ninov

Comment: @devanon, please check my edited answer. I added check for the length and if all are numbers.

Comment: thanks for the additional checks! This works for me @Romeo Ninov

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there's something that needs to be ferreted out, I reach for  `grep` from the toolbox.

```
$ grep -oP '\d+(?:\.\d+)+-\K[^-]+(?=-\d+)' file
```